# C# spliting classes like in C++

Tags: c#, class, ide

Is there any possibility to split classes for a two files like in C++? I mean like defining in header file and declaring in cpp in C++. I've read a bit about partial classes but is it that what i need? If it's not possible can you give me some advices how to manage it cause it looks ugly and messy for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need this? just because it looks messy?

If you use Visual Studio you can hide methods bodies with `Ctrl+M+O`. I use it to get the overview of the code.

Partial classes are design for splinting the generated code from your code. You shouldn't use it to clean up. If your code does look messy try to refactor it e.g. write helper methods, put some logic in a separate class.

C++ has header files only to maintain backward compatibility with C. There are a lot of problems with it e.g. you write a template class and you change the signature in definition, but forgot to change it in declaration and as a result, you get some weird error.

Answer (score 4):

In response to your edit: You can collapse sections of the code if you are concerned about a large class file.

You can use the `partial` keyword.

SomeFile.cs

```
public partial class MyClass
{
}
```

SomeOtherFile.cs

```
public partial class MyClass
{
}
```

Please see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for additional info and restrictions as there are some rules that apply.